# how can I access any <ul> and then any <li> item of its using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

ex: given a facilities portion in a page, and it contains different facilities available in different ul in a column fashion.(so like column 1's ul contains various facilities in list item(li) form).
so i want to access 2nd ul (imagine second column of a table) and its 4th and 5th list-items(li) only.

if I do this, document.querySelector(".text-body li") then I will get data from 1st ul only, but I want it from the second one.

here .text-body is the class and its same for every list.

```
<div class="text-block hospital-facility" id="section-facilities">
<h2 class="text-block-title"></h2>
<div class="facility-list"› 
<h4 class="text-block-list-title">Comfort During Stay</h4>
<div class="text-body add-view-more" data-visible-item="6" data- 
showmore-text="More Details"> 
<ul>...</ul>
<p class="text-right vm-wrp"></p> </div> </div>
<div class="facility-list> 
<h4 class="text-block-list-title">Money Matters</h4> 
  <div class="text-body">
<u1> 
<li>Health insurance coordination</li> 
<li>Medical travel insurance</li>
<li>Foreign currency exchange</li> 
<li>ATM</li> <li>Credit Card< li> 
 </ul>
```

in the above code, the second ul contains various payment methods , I need all of them.
we can do **ul:last-child** but there are around 6-7 ul tags so we need to have something that will select only 2nd ul

Comment: if u want more clarifications , plz let me know but help me out with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I suppose your html looks something like this:

```html
<div id="ulParent">
    <ul>
        <li>li11</li>
        <li>li12</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>li21</li>
        <li>li22</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then you can do:

```js
var secondUl = document.querySelector("#ulParent ul:nth-child(2)");
var fourthLi = secondUl.querySelector("li:nth-child(4)");
var fifthLi = secondUl.querySelector("li:nth-child(5)");
```

**Update after OP added HTML example:**

So with the following `HTML`:

```html
<div class="text-block hospital-facility" id="section-facilities">
    <h2 class="text-block-title"></h2>
    <div class="facility-list">
        <h4 class="text-block-list-title">Comfort During Stay</h4>
        <div class="text-body add-view-more" data-visible-item="6" data-showmore-text="More Details"> 
            <ul><li>...</li></ul>
            <p class="text-right vm-wrp"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="facility-list">
        <h4 class="text-block-list-title">Money Matters</h4> 
        <div class="text-body">
            <ul> 
                <li>Health insurance coordination</li> 
                <li>Medical travel insurance</li>
                <li>Foreign currency exchange</li> 
                <li>ATM</li>
                <li>Credit Card</li> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `ul` is not the 2nd child of its parent so you can't use `:nth-child(2)`.

Instead you need the 1st `ul` of the 2nd `.facility-list`:

```js
var targetUl = document.querySelector("#section-facilities .facility-list:nth-of-type(2) ul");
// then retrieve the `li`s as the previous example shows:
var fourthLi = targetUl.querySelector("li:nth-child(4)");
var fifthLi = targetUl.querySelector("li:nth-child(5)");
```

Note that you can also get your `targetUl` using xpath:

```js
var targetUl = $x("//h4[contains(text(), 'Money Matters')]//following-sibling::div//ul");
```

Comment: please look into the edits made in que, "li:nth-child(4)" is working but I am not able to access 2nd ul particularily using ul:nth-child(2)

Comment: can we do something like 

if(document.querySelector(".text-block-list-title").innerText == Money Matters){
  document.querySelectorAll(#section-facilities ul l)}

is this possible ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should be all good now

Comment: yeah, thnx ....

Comment: Cool, can you mark the answer as resolved please? This way it helps anyone coming accross this